# Facebook graph api like an external url, statistics

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using a Facebook graph api to like an external url:

> Method: POST
>
> URL:
>   https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/{userId}/og.likes
>
> Header:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> Body:
>   access_token={appId}|{appSecrect}&object={"url":"{myUrl}", "title":"{myTitle}"}

It is publishing successfully, returning an Action Id.

**I have 2 problems**:

1. I can keep liking with the same user Id and it will always succeed.
2. I can find my url in **object_url** table, but **link_stat** and **url_like** do not contain any information about this url.

Another strange thing, is if I publish my url like this:

```
access_token={appId}|{appSecrect}&object={myUrl}
```

The first request throws an error "`title is missing`".

The second time the same request returns success.

After that for the same requests it is able to distinguish that a user already liked the url. And I have information in link_stat table.

Comment: I don't think to use an App Access Token makes sense in this case. This is an User action, therefore you'd need to use an User Access Token

Comment: Tobi, I've tried the same requests with an user token - I've got exactly the same behavior =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

### 1. Create an object

This request creates an object "**link**" and returns an Object Id.

> **URL:** /app/objects/website
>
> **Header:** Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> **Body:** ***UrlEncode object's json!***
>
> access_token={appId}|{appSecret}&object={
>       "title":"Happy event",
>       "image":"{img_url}",
>       "url":"{custom_url}",
>       "description":"{description}",
>       "data": {}   }

You can read more here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects

### 2. Like an object

This request will "like" your link on behalf of the user.
It will show in the user's timeline as "User likes a link on you Application site..".

Make sure:
1. User has granted "publish_actions" permission;
2. Your application is apprved for submission of the likes. Otherwise only administrators, developers and testers of you Application can make "likes".
For more information read this :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process

---

> **URL:** /v2.1/{user_id}/og.likes
>
> **Header:** Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> **Body:** object={object_id}&access_token={appId}|{appSecret}

### 3. Get likes for an object

> **URL:** /v2.1/{object_id}/likes?access_token={appId}|{appSecret}